# Do you know any good Database Schema Migration tool?

Tags: php, mysql, database, migration, transformation

I'm currently writing a V2 of application, beyond the code change, some improvements have been done in the database as well as new data (columns/tables).

Now, I need to migrate my V1 data to my V2 application.

Things I need to do is map field in V1 database to field in V2 database, sets default for field that didn't exist in V1, transform DATA TYPE from V1 to V2 (like UNIX_TIMESTAMP to DATETIME).

It is a MySQL to MySQL data migration, so I don't care much about Database Conversion.

Any idea of any tools? Or Will I need to write it myself?

Comment: Enterprise Elements Repository has a built in suite for this activity... but you need to pay.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a V1 system, do the migration by hand (I mean in SQL console), log your commands - the captured commands is cca. the migration script.

Comment: Creating the update script is just one of the tasks: you have to put it into your program (V2), create a mechanism which launches it automatically, but only once, make a "please wait, upgrading db" screen, testing, testing, testing, etc. I think it's better to create the script by hand, avoid messing up something which causes failure on *all* instances.

Answer (score 0):

Try [MySQL WorkBench](http://wb.mysql.com/). It's really good. A one stop solution for data modelling, server administration and SQL development.

Comment: thank you for you answer, but I can't find any tool in mysql workbench to help me to map data for a migration, can you point me any links or something?